# custom horizontal space between entries and their corresponding labels in bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, indentation

I would like to define the horizontal space between entries and their corresponding labels in my .bst bibliography, obtained with `makebst`.
I tried with:

```
\newlength\biblabelsep
\setlength{\biblabelsep}{0.7cm}
```

but it doesn't work.

Could someone suggest me a solution?

Answer (score 4):

Something like this should work (type it in the preamble):

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\advance\leftmargin\labelsep}
  {\labelsep=0.7cm \advance\leftmargin\labelsep}{}{}
```

Answer (score 2):

the width of the label isn't defined in the `.bst` file, but (usually) in the document class or bib style package (e.g. `natbib.sty`).  look in the `.cls` or `.sty` file that you're using for the `thebibliography` environment.  the width of the indent will be set with `\leftmargin`, but the exact components will vary depending on the particular style being used.

in all styles i'm familiar with, this setting is done within a `\list` within the definition of `thebibliography`, so any resetting will depend on either a redefinition of the entire environment, or (if you're lucky) of a subcomponent that can be redefined separately.